# Scan Running .NET App for String Value

Tags: .net, debugging

I have to debug a massive program, and I was wondering if there is a way to scan the memory footprint of a running .NET application, and find a string property that is set to a certain value?

Answer (score 1):

You can using something like Ants Profiler from Red Gate. Ive used it a couple times and its pretty good.  But really any memory profiler could probably tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some memory profilers to take memory snapshots. Snapshots include data about the .NET instance allocations and live instances at the time the snapshot was collected.

Use Ants Profiler, Jetbrains dotTrace profiler http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/ or Memprofiler http://www.memprofiler.com/